# Alternativa de SOAP para WADL em PHP

Tags: php, web-service

Estou tentando enviar alguns parametros para o arquivo libras?wadl via POST do SOAP, mas pelo que estou entendendo o SOAP não reconhece o formato WADL.

Tentei usar algumas coisas como o Httpful e PHP REST Client, mas em nenhuma das duas o post para esse arquivo funcionou.

```
    try 
    {  
        //funcao que sera executada pelo servidor
        $function = 'revisionRequestInfo';

        //Caminho onde sera salvo esse arquivo WSDL ( WADL )
        $options = array( 'location' => 'myURl/services/libras/request/revision' );

        //parametros para gerar o arquivo WDLS ( WADL )
        $arguments = array( 'revisionRequestInfo' => array(
                        'identifier' => 'testIdentifier',
                        'institution' => 'testInstitution',
                        'department' => 'testDepartment',
                        'email' => 'testEmail',
                        'reason' => 'reason' 
                ));

        //caminho onde o arquivo WSDL ( WADL ) esta
        $client = new SoapClient( null, array( 
                    'location' => 'myURL/libras?_wadl'
                     ) );

    //chama o client SOAP 
    $result = $client->__soapCall( $function, $arguments, $options );

    }
    catch ( SoapFault $E ) 
    {  
        echo $E->faultstring ; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

essa maneira está correta, o erro era que o servidor me enviava o caminho forçando a entrada na porta 8080 e o SoapClient não estava reconhecendo o caminho para o servidor.